# List of M new protection levels?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-6.0-marshmallow

Is there a full list of M new protection level list? Where does:

```
com.android.vending.BILLING
com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE
```

belong? To PROTECTION_NORMAL? Full list for reference?

Comment: that's not a permission of android M, that's a permission of Google Play. (so I don't even know if that belongs in a specific protection level)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html#check-for-permission

App Permissions are not covered by this. They are usually enforced by a signature.

Comment: So I assume signature permissions are automatically approved like PROTECTION_NORMAL? And listed permissions above (BILLING, CHECK_LICENSE) are signature permissions?

Comment: Yep. Normal is granted upon install if in the manifest. Yep and those Signature permissions are also granted upon install and validated via another app externally without user interaction